# How to loop through fetch array and display results?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to loop through a fetch array of 3 posts and display the titles of each. However I can only seem to see the first post (1) on the page. I'm not sure if I got the loop working properly?

Here is my current code:

```
export async function getServerSideProps() {

  const posts = [1, 2, 3]

  for (const id of posts) {
    const res = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${id}`)
    const data = await res.json()
    return { props: { data } }
  }

}

const Page = ({data}) => {

  return (
    <div className="main-container">
      <p>{data.title}</p>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Page
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are returning inside the `for` loop.
So the object will be returned after the first iteration.
Try to store the results in a separate array and return outside the loop.

Then display the different titles mapping on the property received:

```
export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const posts = [1, 2, 3];

  const postList = [];
  for (const id of posts) {
    const res = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${id}`);
    postList.push(await res.json());
  }
  return { props: { data: postList } };
}

const Page = ({ data }) => {
  return (
    <div className='main-container'>
        {data.map(post => <p>{post.title}</p>)}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Page;
```

Comment: Do you need to call the function `getServerSideProps()` inside the Page component? Also, using `const` instead of `var`. Does it change the `id`?

Comment: @Kypps the `getServerSideProps` is a NextJS method used for populating the data required by the components before the page is rendered statically by the server. It is a separate method and should not be called inside a component.

Comment: Could you tell me the difference between using `getServerSideProps()` and calling the hook `useEffect` and executing a fetch from a function inside the hook?

Comment: @Kypps By calling the `useEffect` to fetch the data on the client-side you are not taking advantage of the server-side functionalities offered by NextJS. When the data are loaded in `getServerSideProps()` the website page arrives at the client already populated with the necessary data. One advantage for example is that you don't need to handle the loading screens since the data are already there. You can learn more about data fetching in Next JS here https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching